# HTML link to App Store not working in iOS 10.3 Safari

Tags: html, ios, hyperlink, safari, app-store

I have a banner widget that is placed on third-party sites.  The banner ad is to download an app via iOS App Store or Google Play.  The links work perfectly on desktop browsers, but for some reason, on iOS Safari (iOS v10.3) the App Store link is dead yet the Google Play link works fine.

iOS link returns "Safari cannot open this page because the address is invalid". The link is valid, as it works on desktop browsers.

Any suggestions for getting this link to work on iOS Safari?

Below is the HTML and CSS for the links:

**HTML**

```
      <a class="mobile-app-link" href="https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/id12345" target="_blank">
        <span class="mobile-app-span">
          <img class="mobile-app-image" alt="-" src="https://devimages.apple.com.edgekey.net/app-store/marketing/guidelines/images/badge-download-on-the-app-store.svg">
        </span>
      </a>
      <a class="mobile-app-link" href="https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=<id>" target="_blank">
        <span class="mobile-app-span">
          <img class="mobile-app-image" alt="-" src="https://play.google.com/intl/en_us/badges/images/badge_new.png">
        </span>
      </a>
```

**CSS**

```
  .mobile-app-image
    width: 119px
    height: 35px

  .mobile-app-link
    text-align: center
    display: inline-table
    vertical-align: middle
    margin: 0 10px 20px 0

  .mobile-app-span
    display: table-row
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is the ideal solution, but it turns out that what was wrong was the iTunes link itself.  Replacing the link with `http://www.google.com` worked fine.  So I decided to execute the link using JavaScript:

```
<a class="mobile-app-link" href="#" onclick="window.open(encodeURI('https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/id123456'), '_blank', 'location=yes,enableViewPortScale=yes');">
  <span class="mobile-app-span">
    <img class="mobile-app-image" alt="-" src="https://devimages.apple.com.edgekey.net/app-store/marketing/guidelines/images/badge-download-on-the-app-store.svg">
  </span>
</a>
```

The link now opens iTunes in a blank window as expected.